# Are there any difficulty-related achievements in Prey (2017)?

Tags: achievements, prey

I'm usually playing games on hardest difficulty available, with some exceptions. So, I've started playing Prey on Nightmare. Yet, the game has proven to be extremely hard during some enemy encounters, and since then, I've almost lost confidence in my ability to fight against all odds in this game and I'm considering lowering the game difficulty.

But, also I'm an "achievement guy" who sometimes actually tries to get most game achievements. So, since I've done a significant part of the game on the highest difficulty, I would not like to lose the possibility to get achievements like "Finish game on Nightmare difficulty" after doing that much.

So, question is - are there achievements related to difficulty in Prey?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are no difficulty related achievements in the new prey, I won't say which achievement there are for the sake of spoiler prevention. If you want to know more you can look at the [full list here](https://www.polygon.com/prey-guide-walkthrough/2017/5/4/15544862/achievements-trophies-powers-abilities-choices-endings)